# Conflict in angular js with jquery

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am using angular js with existing application in this application jquery and other js also used but when i create one module i got conflict.

error in browser console:

VM2555:6Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=Error%3A%2…Fresources%2Fjs%2Fjquery.min.js%3A2%3A2640)%2C%20%3Canonymous%3E%3A21%3A19)

all js which r used in my application header

```
<script src='<c:url value="/resources/js/jquery.min.js"/>'></script>
    <script src='<c:url value="/resources/js/jquery-ui.min.js"/>'>


    </script><script src='<c:url value="/resources/js/jquery.dialogextend.min.js"/>'></script>

    <!-- IMPORTANT: APP CONFIG -->
    <script src='<c:url value="/resources/js/app.config.js"/>'></script>

    <!-- BOOTSTRAP JS -->
    <script src='<c:url value="/resources/js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"/>'></script>
    <script src='<c:url value="/resources/js/bootstrap/bootstrap-switch.js"/>'></script>
    <script src='<c:url value="/resources/js/bootstrap/bootstrap-table.js"/>'></script>
    <script src='<c:url value="/resources/js/jquery.floatThead.min.js"/>'></script>

    <!-- JARVIS WIDGETS -->
     <script src='<c:url value="/resources/js/jarvis.widget.min.js"/>'></script>

    <!-- JQUERY UI + Bootstrap Slider -->
    <%-- <script src='<c:url value="/resources/js/plugin/bootstrap-slider/bootstrap-slider.min.js"/>'></script>
```

--%>
        
        <%-- '>
 --%>
        
        <%-- '> --%>

```
    <!-- SlideOut -->
    <%-- <script src='<c:url value="/resources/js/plugin/slide-out/slide-out.js"/>'></script>
```

--%>
        
            Your browser is out of date, please update your browser by going to www.microsoft.com/download</h1>

```
    <!-- Demo purpose only -->
    <script src='<c:url value="/resources/js/demo.min.js"/>'></script>

    <!-- MAIN APP JS FILE -->
    <script src='<c:url value="/resources/js/app.min.js"/>'></script>

    <!-- ***************************************************************************** -->

<script src='<c:url value="/resources/js/general-script.js"/>'></script>
<%-- <script src='<c:url value="/resources/js/global-messages.js"/>'></script> --%>
<%--context menu js file --%>
<script src="resources/js/jquery-ui-contextmenu.min.js"></script>

<%-- <script src='<c:url value="/resources/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"/>'></script>

<script src='<c:url value="/resources/js/jquery.dataTables.rowReordering.js"/>'></script>   

<script src='<c:url value="/resources/js/dataTables.colReorder.js"/>'></script>
 --%>
<script src='<c:url value="/resources/js/jquery.tablednd.js"/>'></script>
<script src='<c:url value="/resources/js/jquery.dragtable.js"/>'></script>

<script src='<c:url value="/resources/js/dropzone.js"/>'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src='<c:url value="/resources/js/jspdf/jspdf.min.js"/>'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src='<c:url value="/resources/js/jspdf/html2canvas.js"/>'></script>
```

'>

```
<script src='<c:url value="/resources/js/jquery.blockUI.js"/>'></script>
<script src='<c:url value="/resources/js/jquery.sortable.min.js"/>'></script>   
<script src='<c:url value="/resources/js/ChartNew.js"/>'></script>
<script src='<c:url value="/resources/js/angular/angular.min.js"/>'></script>
<script src='<c:url value="/resources/js/angular/angular-route.min.js"/>'></script>
```

Comment: Does your /resources/js/app.config.js use app module?

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes jquery and angularjs third party plugins conflict to each other that cause to not to load angularjs file properly. Try to add jquery plugins one by one and test with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try change the order of src. Your app.min.js must be below angular.min.js and angular-route.min.js

Answer (score 0):

Here you go the below is a link , which might solve your **injection error**
https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr